# Aggregating and presenting user related messages to end user in Java

Tags: java, cross-cutting-concerns

I am developing a **Rest API** using **Apache CXF** and currently I am working on finding a way to aggregate client related messages in order to send them back to the client when it is necessary.

**For example**, lets say that a client invokes one of my resources with a `POST` request in order to add data to the collection. If the client sends incorrect data then a `HTTP 400` response will be sent. What I want is to send in the response payload useful messages on why the data were invalid. Those messages may come from different classes within my application. What I currently do is I have developed a MessageQueue class (shown below) which is responsible to manage this cross cutting concern.

Is this a good way of doing it? Is there any framework for doing something similar or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

**MessageQueue.java**

```
public class MessageQueue {

    private static Map<String, Queue<String>> messagePool = new HashMap<String, Queue<String>>();

    public static synchronized boolean createSession() {
        String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();

        if (messagePool.containsKey(threadName)) {
            messagePool.remove(threadName);
        }

        messagePool.put(threadName, new LinkedList<String>());
        return true;
    }

    public static synchronized void addMessage(String message) {
        Queue<String> q = messagePool.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if(q != null){
            q.add(message);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void removeMessage(String message) {
        Queue<String> q = messagePool.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if(q != null){
            q.remove(message);
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void terminateSession() {
        messagePool.remove(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static synchronized String getMessages() {
        Queue<String> q = messagePool.get(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        String messages = "";
        // Concatenate strings
        while (q != null && !q.isEmpty()) {
            //resolve new line feeds and escape all necessary characters
            messages += q.poll().replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "").replace("\"", "\\\"") + " - ";         
        }
        //remove last " - "
        if(!messages.equals("")){
            messages = messages.substring(0, messages.length()-3);  
        }
        return messages;
    }
}
```